# Multiple m:m relationships LEFT JOIN giving duplicate records

Tags: mysql

DB noob here.

I have a table named `invoice` with a m:m relationship with a few other tables via junction tables:

- `invoice_customer`
- `invoice_creator`
- `invoice_deposit`
- `invoice_withdrawal`
- `invoice_payment_method`

I'm trying to execute a query that will `LEFT JOIN` all of the data of these m:m relationships, however, seemingly at random, I'm getting duplicate results. Sometimes it gives the right amount, then when some state is modified it will give duplicates, and I can't seem to figure out why.

For example, this query gives me a result of "1" given I have one record matching the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM invoice
JOIN account_invoice
    ON account_invoice.account_id = ?
    AND account_invoice.invoice_id = invoice.id
WHERE invoice.deleted_at IS NULL
```

But this query gives me 4 duplicate records instead of 1:

```
SELECT invoice.*, account.*, customer.*, payment_method.*, deposit.*, withdrawal.*
FROM invoice
LEFT JOIN account_invoice
    ON account_invoice.invoice_id = invoice.id
LEFT JOIN account
    ON account.id = account_invoice.account_id
LEFT JOIN invoice_customer
    ON invoice_customer.invoice_id = invoice.id
LEFT JOIN customer
    ON customer.id = invoice_customer.customer_id
LEFT JOIN invoice_payment_method
    ON invoice_payment_method.invoice_id = invoice.id
LEFT JOIN payment_method
    ON payment_method.id = invoice_payment_method.payment_method_id
LEFT JOIN invoice_deposit
    ON invoice.id = invoice_deposit.invoice_id
LEFT JOIN transaction AS deposit
    ON deposit.id = invoice_deposit.transaction_id
LEFT JOIN invoice_withdrawal
    ON invoice.id = invoice_withdrawal.invoice_id
LEFT JOIN transaction AS withdrawal
    ON withdrawal.id = invoice_withdrawal.transaction_id
WHERE account.id = ?
    AND invoice.deleted_at IS NULL
ORDER BY invoice.id DESC
LIMIT ?,?
```

Comment: They are not really duplicates. If you have an invoice related with 2  deposits and 2 withdrawals, your query will rightfully return 4 rows. That's what you asked for.

Comment: If there are also 3 related payment methods the result will be 12 rows. One for each combination of related deposits, withdrawals and payment methods.

Comment: It seems like `payment_method` would be tied to deposit and to withdrawal??

Comment: @RickJames Yes it's used for the withdrawal mostly, but I just attach it to the invoice for now.

Comment: @yper-crazyhat-cubeᵀᴹ Good point, however there is only one result in each of the junction tables.

Comment: If there is only one result, then don't use junction tables.  For that matter, don't use separate tables!  If it is really 1:many, then don't use junction tables, simply have an `id` in the "many" table to point to the "1" table.

Comment: @Lansana I seriously doubt that. If there was a single result - **in every junction table** - then you would get 1 row in the result of the query. Start your query (the 2nd one) from very basic, only with `FROM invoice` (keep the WHERE, remove the LIMIT). Then add each join, one by one and write down how many rows you get in the result. You'll find how many tables have more than 1 related rows.

Comment: @yper-crazyhat-cubeᵀᴹ There was actually another join I omitted from my example above, which was pulling related data from one of the joins above. That item has more than one record, which explains my "duplicates". Thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one row of output for each Invoice, you need to figure out what to do with multiple customers tied to that one invoice.  (Etc.)  Here's one approach:

```
SELECT i.*,
       GROUP_CONCAT( 
           ( SELECT c.name FROM invoice_customers AS ic
                           JOIN customers AS c  USING(customer_id)
                           WHERE ic.invoice_id = i.invoice_id
           ) SEPARATOR ", "
                   ) AS customers
    FROM invoices AS i
    ...
```